# Name of a plane graph with no dangling edges

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a name for a connected plane graph such that every edge lies in a cycle that bounds a face?
So there are no "dangling" edges.
The graph then partitions the plane into face regions.
Just seeking the proper terminology.

Comment: Are you familiar with ["$k$-connectedness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory))? A graph is $k$-connected if removing some $k-1$ vertices would disconnect the graph. To prevent "dangling edges". you can require your graph to be (at least) $2$-connected. (This also prevents characteristics other than dangling edges.) If you're specifically targeting planar graphs that correspond to the skeleta of a convex polyhedra, then [the key $k$ is $3$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyhedralGraph.html).

Comment: @Blue: Thank you, k-connectivity is what I need.

Comment: The proper word for "dangling edges" might be "pendant vertices." However, a planar graph with no pendant vertices is not exactly what you want.